# is there a way to efficiently query a SQL Database every x seconds

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a matchmaking system through the use of an online database which registers "Searching" Players and waits until someone has matched with them. for this I have a portion of the code that needs to update every x seconds in order to check if a match has been found, my code so far is this

```
import pymysql
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
import socket
from requests import get
import time, threading


UserIP = get_IP().pop
UserIP = UserIP()
self.b1.setText("Searching...")
self.update()
def update_search():
            Player2 = None
            WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = 5
            ticker = threading.Event()
            while Player2 is None and not ticker.wait(WAIT_TIME_SECONDS):
                c.execute("SELECT Player2 FROM Games WHERE Player1=%s",(UserIP))
                try:
                    Player2 = c.fetchone()[0]
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                print(Player2)
            print("hi1")
```

However this code causes my PyQt GUI to freeze up and crash, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

EDIT: The rest of the code is not included because it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: You could add an index on Player1 making the query faster. Also, since you're only using the first result, perhaps also add that to the query.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by running a thread and calling the method this way; Here's the code

```
found_game = False
def update_search():
    global found_game
    UserIP = get_IP().pop
    UserIP = UserIP()
    print(UserIP)
    Player2 = None
    WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = 5
    ticker = threading.Event()
    while found_game is False and not ticker.wait(WAIT_TIME_SECONDS):
        c.execute("SELECT Player2 FROM Games WHERE Player1=%s",(UserIP))
        try:
            Player2 = c.fetchone()[0]
            if Player2 is not None:
                found_game = True
            else:
                pass
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

And in the actual code I ran this:

```
            x = threading.Thread(target=update_search, daemon=True)
            x.start()
```